# Accessing Android Root Privileges Without Having To Root The Phone

Tags: android, operating-system, su, rooted-device

I'm trying to access the root privileges of my android phone (OS 6.0.1 Samsung) without rooting the phone. It can be an app/service anything as long as I can get root access without having to root the phone.

I found out that there are some code/command you can do using 'su' but it requires a rooted phone. Can you use 'su' command in an unrooted android phones to access root privileges? If so, how? Or is there a way you can use root access without rooting the phone- by any means? Command lines? Third-party tools?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162397/understand-root-and-su and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18601/what-exactly-is-superuser-apk-and-su and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27321/why-cant-the-su-binary-simply-be-copied-techical-response-please/

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to access the root privileges of my android phone (OS 6.0.1 Samsung) without rooting the phone.

By definition, that is not possible. That is akin to demanding that something be purple without being purple.

> Can you use 'su' command in an unrooted android phones to access root privileges?

No. For starters, it will not exist.

> Or is there a way you can use root access without rooting the phone- by any means? Command lines? Third-party tools?

No.

Answer (score 1):

SU is basically a binary that plays an important role in Android rooting and it is normally placed in the /system partition. It will be used when other apps need superuser permission, so if you don't have it there is no way to do this.

Check this link for further information `https://www.kingoapp.com/troubleshoot/su-warning-window-on-kingo-superuser.htm`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get root acces without su binary files in xbin or bin folder...and sudo was previously used in lower android version long ago this command can give you root acces without root but now not exist in any newer version...
Try to google your problem i am sure if u have samsung phone there must a procedure for root... happy rooting goodluck